# send_keys(Keys.RETURN) submitting 1 extra character (python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to automate a login process.

To do so, I am using send_keys('email') and send_keys('password') in their respective fields like so:

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
email.send_keys('e@mail.com')

pwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
pwd.send_keys('pwd12345')
```

These two steps are successful. Now, I would like to use the "return" key to submit the login credentials and be logged in. To do so, I have tried:

```
pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The password I am attempting to enter is 8 characters long. After the 8 characters have been entered, pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) enters a 9th character into the password field JUST before the credentials are submitted, resulting in "incorrect email address or password".

I have also tried:

`email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` - which also returns "incorrect email address or password"

`pwd.submit()` - which clears the email and password fields completely and does not log in (?)

Thoughts?

Comment: can you try with Keys.ENTER?

Comment: Selenium, WebDriver type (gecko/chrome/ie) type & version, Browser type & version please. Thanks

Comment: Your program works perfectly on my machine. I am able to successfully log in to Paypal. Can you please try again

Answer (score 0):

Can you try code below?

```
pwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(pwd,'pwd12345').send_keys_to_element(pwd, Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

Comment: Using your code clears the email and password fields completely and does not log in, the same way that pwd.submit() does. FWIW, this is a PayPal login form. Perhaps a security implementation could cause this?

Comment: @pizzaman5000 Can you give me the URL of Paypal? I'm testing on my Paypal account and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Considering you are trying to login in to your [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/in/home) Account with a valid set of credentials the following code block works through all the 3 options as in:

- Using `click()`
- Using `Keys.ENTER`
- Using `Keys.RETURN`

Having said that I will suggest you to consider using the `click()` and `clear()` methods before entering any text into any `input tag`. Here is the working code block:

```
driver.get('https://www.paypal.com/in/home');
driver.implicitly_wait(20);
driver.find_element_by_id('ul-btn').click();
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
email.click();
email.clear();
email.send_keys('debanjan.selenium@gmail.com');
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password');
password.click();
password.clear();
password.send_keys('dev_anjan');

#Using Keys.ENTER
#password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER);

#Using Keys.RETURN
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);

#Using LogIn Button Click
#login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')
#login_button.click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way, it's working for me:

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
email.send_keys('e@mail.com')

pwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
pwd.send_keys('pwd12345')
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnLogin"]')
login_button.click()
```

Insted of pressing Enter on the password field you should do what a normal guy does and press the `Log In` button.